# iseries member browswer not showing as an option

Tags: ibm-midrange, member, rpg

i installed Visual Studio Code along with all ibmi extensions. I am able to browse objects and IFS, but there is no option to browse source members.

Any idea why that option would not be available?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following:

1. Make sure your filter is using the `*SRCPF` type. That means it will let you browse source files instead of objects.
2. Try disabling SQL and then seeing if members show up.
3. In the Code for IBM i 'Help and Support' view, click 'Report an Issue' to raise an issue on GitHub.